# How to grab value from array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am pulling an array from my DB that is saved in this format:

```
[categories] => [
    {"category":"Exit Sign"},
    {"category":"Leaving"},
    {"category":"Illuminated"},
    {"category":"Sign"},
    {"category":"Red"},
    {"category":"Warning Sign"},
    {"category":"Above"}
]
```

How can I loop through each {} and get the category?

Edit: I have attempted passing each JSON array from my DB through json_decode() but I am getting the following error "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given..." Any idea what would cause this?

Edit 2: Here is the var_dump output for just one row in my DB:

```
array(1) {
  ["categories"]=>
  string(845) "[{"category":"Built Structure"},{"category":"The Americas"},{"category":"Sky"},{"category":"New York City"},{"category":"Manhattan - New York City"},{"category":"USA"},{"category":"History"},{"category":"Suspension Bridge"},{"category":"Brooklyn - New York"},{"category":"Brooklyn Bridge"},{"category":"Scenics"},{"category":"Skyscraper"},{"category":"River"},{"category":"Downtown District"},{"category":"East River"},{"category":"Cityscape"},{"category":"Bridge - Man Made Structure"},{"category":"City"},{"category":"Lighting Equipment"},{"category":"Arch"},{"category":"Urban Skyline"},{"category":"Architecture"},{"category":"Sunset"},{"category":"Night"},{"category":"Modern"},{"category":"Urban Scene"},{"category":"Tower"},{"category":"Famous Place"},{"category":"Gate"},{"category":"Outdoors"},{"category":"East"},{"category":"Travel"}]"
}
```

Got it! I had to pass $array['categories'] into json_decode and then it worked properly. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted?

Comment: could you please use `var_dump($your_array_from_db);` and post it ? Here you used `print_r()` and this does not print any info about data type

Comment: Updated with what I have attempted, and also a var_dump @Bob0t

Comment: @tibsar updated with a var_dump of one lined returned from the DB

Comment: Try `json_decode($array['categories'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, So you are new to this world. You are welcome.

Let your array value is names as `$json`. This value is a json format, so for access this value you need to decode them. You need to use a function called [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), which has two parameter, the first one is string where you pass your variable `json`, an second one is `bool` where you pass true or false.

You have to pass when you want your array as associative not object. Here i ignore the second option, so my return array is object.

After decoding your json string you have an array, now you have to use a loop `foreach` to browse all the elements of the array. As you can see in the resultant array below, the array is multi-dimensional so after applying a `foreach` loop you just reach the first depth. For getting the value of `category` you should need to use `->` after `$val` which is the first depth array.

```
$json = '[{"category":"Exit Sign"},{"category":"Leaving"},{"category":"Illuminated"},{"category":"Sign"},{"category":"Red"},{"category":"Warning Sign"},{"category":"Above"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json); //Also you can pass $yourArr['categories'];

foreach($arr as $val){
    echo $val->category."<br/>";
}
```

After decoding your array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Exit Sign
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Leaving
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Illuminated
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Sign
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Red
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Warning Sign
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [category] => Above
        )

)
```

**Result:**

```
Exit Sign
Leaving
Illuminated
Sign
Red
Warning Sign
Above
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've already tried using json_decode() but it returns an error saying "json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given."

Comment: Try passing in the first index of categories

Comment: There we go, got it. I had to pass ['categories'] with my array in json_decode and it did the trick... thanks for your help! @tibsar